# Rename file names in current directory and all subdirectories

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I have 4 files with the following names in different directories and subdirectories

```
tag0.txt, tag1.txt, tag2.txt and tag3.txt
```

and wish to rename them as  `tag0a.txt, tag1a.txt ,tag2a.txt and tag3a.txt` in  all directories and  subdirectories.

Could anyone help me out  using a shell script?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ rename -n 's/\.txt$/a\.txt/' **/*.txt
foo/bar/tag2.txt renamed as foo/bar/tag2a.txt
foo/tag1.txt renamed as foo/tag1a.txt
tag0.txt renamed as tag0a.txt
```

Remove `-n` to rename after checking the result - It is the "dry run" option.

Comment: You might want `**/tag[0123].txt` instead of `**/*.txt` to suit the OP

Answer (score 3):

This can of course be done with find:

```
find . -name 'tag?.txt' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" ${1%.*}a.${1##*.}' -- {} \;
```

Comment: I should probably note that this version doesn't care what the extension is, just that it has one. Selecting a different set of files to rename will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a posix shell script (checked with dash):

```
visitDir() {
    local file
    for file in "$1"/*; do
            if [ -d "$file" ]; then
                    visitDir "$file";
            else
                    if [ -f "$file" ] && echo "$file"|grep -q '^.*/tag[0-3]\.txt$'; then
                            newfile=$(echo $file | sed 's/\.txt/a.txt/')
                            echo mv "$file" "$newfile"
                    fi
            fi

    done
}

visitDir .
```

If you can use bashisms, just replace the inner IF with:

```
if [[ -f "$file" && "$file" =~ ^.*/tag[0-3]\.txt$ ]]; then
    echo mv "$file" "${file/.txt/a.txt}"
fi
```

First check that the result is what you expected, then possibly remove the "echo" in front of the mv command.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Perl script version of `rename` that may be on your system:

```
find . -name 'tag?.txt' -exec rename 's/\.txt$/a$&/' {} \;
```

Using the binary executable version of `rename`:

```
find . -name 'tag?.txt' -exec rename .txt a.txt {} \;
```

which changes the first occurrence of ".txt". Since the file names are constrained by the `-name` argument, that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this good enough?

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ find . -name tag?.txt
./a/tag0.txt
./b/tagb.txt
./c/tag1.txt
./c/d/tag3.txt
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ for txtfile in $(find . -name 'tag?.txt'); do \
 mv $txtfile ${txtfile%%.txt}a.txt; done
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ find . -name tag*.txt
./a/tag0a.txt
./b/tagba.txt
./c/d/tag3a.txt
./c/tag1a.txt
```

Don't actually put the backslash into the command, and if you do, expect a '>' prompt on the next line. I didn't put that into the output to avoid confusion, but I didn't want anybody to have to scroll either.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I understand well, the actual commands are "for txtfile in $(find . -name 'tag?.txt'); do \
 mv $txtfile ${txtfile%%.txt}a.txt; done"