# How to rename files in a directory and all subdirectories

Tags: unix

How do you replace the phrase "Full Tilt" with "FullTilt" in all files in a directory and subdirectories under that directory (and all sub-directories under those subdirectories and so on)?

Comment: Paste some part of code you have at least and describe where  you have a problem.

Comment: with the great tool `find`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename file names in current directory and all subdirectories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593620/rename-file-names-in-current-directory-and-all-subdirectories)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string

Comment: Are you renaming files or editing the contents of the files?  Your title suggests renaming; your question suggests editing ('in all files in a directory').  If you said 'in all file names in a directory', your question would be consistent with your title.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it, but you should be able to do it more or less like this:

First, create a script called 'rename.sh', make it executable and save it with the following content:

```
#! /bin/bash
folder=`dirname $1`
oldname=`basename $1`
newname=`echo "$oldname" | sed 's/Full Tilt/FullTilt/g'`
mv "$folder/$oldname" "$folder/$newname"
```

Then, run the following command from inside your directory:

```
find -name "*Full Tilt*" -type file -exec "rename.sh" "{}" ";"
```

It can probably be done with a one-liner on find (instead of using a script), but it won't be readable and it will contain too many escapes to follow...

Comment: It's generally better to use the `$(...)` notation in place of the back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
find . -name '*xx*' -print | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)xx\(.*\)$/\1xx\2 \1yy\2 /g' | xargs -n2 mv
```

Where '*xx*' ist the search string for the file names.
sed replaces the xx with yy and pipes that to xargs
xargs takes now (-n2) two parameters (old and new name) and execute mv with both parms.

That is only the start point, try it in a safe environment :-)

You have first rename the files ( -type=f ) after that you rename the path ( -type=d ). If you change this order the mv will fail while the directory is renamed while changing the next file name :-)

If there are spaces in the file names, you have to use print0 instead of print. But then you also have to change the sed part... I think the rest is your homework :-)

Feel free to ask if something will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with `find` and `sed`

```
 find /path/to/your/dir -type f -exec sed -i 's/Full Tilt/FullTilt/g' "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Boy, was it tricky! First you have to reverse the output of `find` to start from the deepest files and directories. Then to make it work with filenames containing spaces. And then, not all `rename` commands are equal. You need the one from Larry Wall, which takes a Perl regex to define the renaming. Check `man rename` first.

```
find foo | tac | while read i; do echo $i; rename 's/(.*)Full Tilt/$1FullTilt/' "$i"; done
```